# Using Awaitility to verify a method wasn't called during duration

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, awaitility

Is is possible to use awaitility to ensure a method wasn't called during the await?

I have tried using

```
@Test
void testThatSomeMethodWasntCalled(){
await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> someClass.someMethod())
}
```

But there doesn't appear to be a negative version of untilAsserted().

Currently I am using

```
@Test
void testThatSomeMethodWasntCalled(){
await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
verify(someClass, never()).someMethod()
}
```

However the above feels like a glorfied Thread.sleep(...)

Any help would be appricated!
Jonny

Comment: Would there be a side-effect if that unwanted method was invoked?  If yes, check the side-effect does not exist.

Comment: The someClass is actually a mock so there’s no side effect

Comment: The mock could set a boolean `wasMethodWasInvoked` to true if the method was invoked, then could `await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> !wasMethodWasInvoked)`. But the second example looks easier to read.

Comment: There was actually an issue with the `await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, it doesnt wait unless it has .until(...) so my test was actually not testing anything. The cleanest alternative that i have found is not using Awailtillity, but just using Mockitio. `verify(someClass, after(8000).never()).someMethod()`